# Searching and replacing existing python script with updated functions

Tags: python

I need to write a Python script to update another Python script so that older pieces of code will be replaced by newer functions. Basically whenever it sees something like "Model...Read() or Model...Write(x), it should replace them with updated strings. For example, the script should find the string "Model.CB1_OV_En.Read()" and replace it with "MAPort.Read(Model.CB1_OV_En).Value". There are many variables to update, and doing this by hand will be tedious, so I'm curious if there is a good approach to automate this. I have the string replacement functions done, but I'm not sure how to automate finding the variables in the .py file.

```
def main():
    textfile = "C:\\Desktop\\Trip_Logic.py"
    with open(textfile, 'r') as file :
        filedata = file.read()
    readString     = "Model....Read()"
    if readString in filedata:
        print readString[2:7]
    filedata = filedata.replace(readString, convertReadHILAPI(readString))
    with open(textfile, 'w') as file:
        file.write(filedata)
    #filedata = filedata.replace(string, convertWriteHILAPI(writeString))

    ##############################################################
    #Example:
    readString1     = "Model.CB1_OV_En.Read()"
    newReadString1  = "MAPort.Read(Model.CB1_OV_En).Value"
    readString2     = "Model.CB2_OV_En.Read()"
    newReadString2  = "MAPort.Read(Model.CB2_OV_En).Value"
    ##############################################################
    writeString1    = "Model.CB1_OV_En.Write(1)"
    newWriteString1 = "MAPort.Write(Model.CB1_OV_En, Float(1))"
    writeString2    = "Model.CB2_OV_En.Write(1)"
    newWriteString2 = "MAPort.Write(Model.CB2_OV_En, Float(1))"
    ##############################################################

def convertReadHILAPI(string):
    variableStartIndex = 6
    variableStopIndex  = string.find(".Read")
    varName = string[variableStartIndex:variableStopIndex]
    cmd = 'newVarName = "MAPort.Read(Model.%s).Value" % (varName)'
    exec cmd
    return newVarName

def convertWriteHILAPI(string):
    variableStartIndex = 6
    variableStopIndex  = string.find(".Write")
    valueStartIndex = string.find("(")
    valueStopIndex = string.find(")")
    varName = string[variableStartIndex:variableStopIndex]
    value = string[valueStartIndex+1:valueStopIndex]
    cmd = 'newVarName = "MAPort.Write(Model.%s, Float(%s)) " % (varName, value)'
    exec cmd
    return newVarName

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub). This is more pythonic way to achieve what you want:

```
import re


def main():
    fname = r'C:\Desktop\Trip_Logic.py'
    with open(fname) as reader:
        data = reader.read()

    # Model.XXX.Read() => MAPort.Read(Model.XXX).Value
    data = re.sub(r'(Model\.(.+)\.Read\(\))',
                  r'MAPort.Read(Model.\2).Value',
                  data)

    # Model.XXX.Write(N) => MAPort.Write(Model.XXX, Float(N))
    data = re.sub(r'(Model\.(.+)\.Write\((\d+)\))',
                  r'MAPort.Write(Model.\2, Float(\3))',
                  data)

    with open(fname, 'w') as writer:
        writer.write(data)
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you